# How add value in the beginning of the array with a key?

Tags: php

I know about function `array_unshift()`, but that adds to array with a autoincrement `key`.
For this code:

```
$messages[$obj_result['from']] = $obj_result;
```

I need to add value `$obj_result` in the beginning of the array. So, last added value will be in the beginning of array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do somthing like this

```
$array = array("a"=>1,"b"=>2,"d"=>array("e"=>1));
$newArray["c"] = 3;
echo "<pre>";
print_r(array_merge($newArray,$array));
```

in array_merge first argument will be your that key value pair that you want to add in beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming as an array (with your desire key) you can use operator + :

```
$messages = obj_result + $messages;
```

Answer (score 0):

From the manual:

```
while literal keys won't be touched
```

So you can just prepend the element, assuming the `from` key of the `$obj_result` variable is a string, all the key's will stay the same, while your new element is still on the beginning of the array.